# Deployment problems of a Spring Boot project on Wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE project with Java 1.8 using Wildfly 20 as the application server, but I am experiencing several problems.

This is the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.eug</groupId>
    <artifactId>ComicsArchive</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ComicsArchive</name>
    <description></description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
              <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
              <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
           <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
           <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2</version> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> 
     <configuration>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
      <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
      <warName>ROOT</warName>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-releases</id>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>spring-releases</id>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Trying to read the log it seems that it all revolves around a jsp-related error (but I don't use any, I just have an html page managed with Spring MVC and thymeleaf), maybe wildfly has some libraries inside it that have to be forcibly configured, I don't know..
However by running the project from the Boot Dashboard everything works, while just trying to deploy it gives errors, so it's definitely a matter of configuration/incompatibility with wildfly.

Any advice? Thanks

This is the resulting stacktrace:

```
14:25:44,705 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager

14:25:44,705 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.Version.isJsf23(Version.java:62)

14:25:44,705 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.addELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:136)

14:25:44,705 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.addELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:221)

14:25:44,707 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.jboss.as.jsf-injection//org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplication.<init>(WeldApplication.java:60)

14:25:44,708 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.jboss.as.jsf-injection//org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.WeldApplicationFactory.getApplication(WeldApplicationFactory.java:52)

14:25:44,711 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

14:25:44,711 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

14:25:44,711 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

14:25:44,714 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)

14:25:44,714 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)

14:25:44,714 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)

14:25:44,714 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)

14:25:44,715 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

14:25:44,715 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

14:25:44,717 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

14:25:44,717 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

14:25:44,718 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

14:25:44,719 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124)  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

14:25:44,812 SEVERE [javax.faces] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory. Attempting to find backup.
14:25:44,812 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory. 

14:25:45,059 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:40)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:849)

14:25:45,061 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 124) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCOracle-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCOracle-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:254)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@20.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:283)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)

Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:205)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:40)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP11//com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:849)

14:25:45,609 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "SpringMVCOracle-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"SpringMVCOracle-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}

14:25:45,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringMVCOracle-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
WFLYCTL0448: 1 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
```

Comment: Springboot is a package to run code in a separate environment that doesn't need a traditional application server like Wildfly.  Running Springboot inside of a server names no sense - you're running a server inside of a server.  Why do you want to mix the two?

Comment: @stdunbar And in which server does SpringBoot run? I thought it already had Tomcat integrated, but for the operations I have to do I needed access to a wide range of Java EE libraries, which a webcontainer cannot provide (that is why I had excluded its dependencies in the POM); that is why I had opted for the free version of Jboss.
How would you deploy a SpringBoot project?
Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: A SpringBoot project is generally standalone but, you're right, it's only Tomcat which isn't a full JEE stack.  I've been using Quarkus for the type of work you're describing as it gives me the parts of JEE I need but not everything.  And it's setup for Docker/Kubernetes.  That might require some porting depending on how deeply you've integrated Spring overall.  There is support for many Spring systems but not all.  And it is really a back end system - JSF would have to be added on.